# Double "active" class in image carousel

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an image carousel using HTML and PHP.

The image carousel works as follow:

1. This image carousel consists of two components: main image area and a thumbnail area (id = banner-mouseover-area).
2. The banner-mouseover-area consist of thumbnail images of the main images and it will only appear when user mouse over the main image area.
3. When the user mouseover a specific thumbnail image, the “active” image of the main image area will be changed to the mouseover image.
4. zoom_image (JS) function is written to identify the id of the mouseover thumbnail image so as to set the main image as “active”.

However, sometimes after mouseover the thumbnail image, the image carousel will seems to have 2 “active” class happening at the same time. As such it created second image carousel right below the original one. But once the original image carousel auto slide to the next image in queue, the second image carousel will disappear automatically.

How should I go about resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<div id='carouselCustom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
  <div class='carousel-outer'>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class='carousel-inner'>
      <?php $bannerCnt=1; $bannerCnt2=0; foreach($images as $image) { ?>
      <div id="<?php echo 'slide_'.$bannerCnt2; ?>" class="<?php if($bannerCnt == 1) { echo 'active'; } ?> item">
        <a id="imagezoom" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                                        <img id="zoomImage" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$image['banner_path']; ?>" height="585px" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" onmouseout="bannerOffPreview()"/>
                                    </a>
      </div>
      <?php $bannerCnt++; $bannerCnt2++; } ?>

      <div id='banner-mouseover-area' style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px; display: none;">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class='carousel-indicators mCustomScrollbar'>
          <?php $thumbnailCnt=0; foreach($images as $imageThumb) { ?>
          <li data-transition="flip" data-target="#carouselCustom" data-change-to="<?php echo $thumbnailCnt; ?>" class="<?php if($thumbnailCnt == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
            <a onmouseover='return zoom_image($(this));' rel="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path'].'_&'.$thumbnailCnt; ?>" href="<?php echo $imageThumb['url']; ?>">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path']; ?>" width="160px" onmouseover="bannerPreview()" />
                                            </a>
          </li>
          <?php $thumbnailCnt++; } ?>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <!-- Left -->
    <div id="leftControl" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -20px; left: 20px;" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows default round" data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide='prev'>
      <div class="tp-arr-allwrapper">
        <div class="tp-arr-iwrapper">
          <div class="tp-arr-imgholder" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-imgholder2"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-titleholder"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-subtitleholder"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right -->
    <div id="rightControl" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -20px; right: 20px;" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows default round" data-target="#carouselCustom" data-slide='next'>
      <div class="tp-arr-allwrapper">
        <div class="tp-arr-iwrapper">
          <div class="tp-arr-imgholder" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-imgholder2"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-titleholder"></div>
          <div class="tp-arr-subtitleholder"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function zoom_image(img) {
  //Get the rel value of the image
  var div_id = '';
  var fullpath = img.attr('rel');
  var splitpath = fullpath.split("_&");
  var image_name = splitpath[0];
  var slide_id = splitpath[1];
  var new_slide_id = "slide_" + slide_id;
  document.getElementById('zoomImage').src = image_name;

  var currentSlide = document.getElementsByClassName('active item')[0].id;

  console.log(new_slide_id);
  //For loop to remove class and add class to the selected image
  for (i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++) {
    div_id = "slide_" + i;
    if (div_id !== new_slide_id) {
      //Remove all active class from the div
      var removeB = document.getElementById(div_id);
      removeB.className = "";
      removeB.className = "item";
    } else {
      //Add active class to the div
      var mouseoverSlide = document.getElementById(new_slide_id);
      mouseoverSlide.className = "";
      mouseoverSlide.className = "item active";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using Twitter Bootstrap, you most likely are also using jQuery (at least, Bootstrap uses it), so why not use it to your advantage?

You could do something like:

```
function zoom_image(img) {
    //Get the rel value of the image
    var div_id = '';
    var fullpath = img.attr("rel");
    var splitpath = fullpath.split("_&");
    var image_name = splitpath[0];
    var slide_id = splitpath[1];
    var new_slide_id = "slide_" + slide_id;
    $('#zoomImage').attr("src", image_name);

    $(".active.item").removeClass("active");
    $("#"+new_slide_id).addClass("active");
}
```

I haven't tested this code, try it out

================ EDIT ================

After re-reading your code, you could simplify it a bit more:

For starters, you could use data-* attributes in your code so you don't have to fight your way to the id of the image. Where you have:

```
<a onmouseover='return zoom_image($(this));' ...>
```

you could have something like

```
<a onmouseover='return zoom_image($(this));' data-image="<?php echo BANNER_PATH.'assets/landing_banner_images/'.$imageThumb['banner_path']; ?>" data-target="<?php echo 'slide_".$thumbnailCnt; ?>" ...>
```

and then simply:

```
function zoom_image(img) {
    var image_name = img.attr("data-image");
    var new_slide_id = img.attr("data-target");
    $('#zoomImage').attr("src", image_name);

    $(".active.item").removeClass("active");
    $("#"+new_slide_id).addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Tested the code and it still creates a second image carousel right below the first one.

Comment: Hmm. You have to do the same thing with the indicators, I guess. Because you're also setting one of them as active, and you don't unset it